# How to convert a “String” value to “Type” in Angular 2 TS

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

This is my current object, Home refers to my import

```
import { Home } from '../home/home';


  arr = [
      { name: "Home", root: "Home", icon: "calc" }
    ];
```

This is what i want to achieve:

```
 import { Home } from '../home/home';
 arr = [
          { name: "Home", root: Home, icon: "calc" }
        ];
```

Im getting a error because "Home" is a string. eval() works but i'm looking for a alternative

Working code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      arr[i].root = eval(arr[i].root);
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `root: new Home()` ? You can't refer to import referance until you create or inject an instance.

Comment: Please provide here a code of `Home` object (`'../home/home.ts'`).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's the exact error message? What code does cause the error?

Comment: I just want to transform "Home"  to Home  (without the quotes)

Comment: this code is working, but i'm wondering if there is a alternative for this:      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      arr[i].root = eval(arr[i].root);
    }

Comment: You shouldn't be using `eval`. This should be working: `{ name: "Home", root: Home, icon: "calc" }`. What error do you get for that?

Comment: @Nitzan Yes, but im getting my data remote from a json object. So the default json object has quotes

Comment: What is `eval(arr[i].root)` supposed to return? A class instance?

Comment: @Gunter it must be linked to my import {Home}  I don't know if that's a instance lol

Comment: No idea what that means. I think you should elaborate a bit more on what you try to accomplish. At least I can't make any sense of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is your situation:
You are receiving a json from a server which has in certain fields names of classes that you need to use in runtime.
The names are strings and you need to get the classes they refer to.

You can indeed use `eval` as you used, but take into account that it is recommended to avoid using `eval`, especially when using it on data received from remote, for example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!):

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.

If you still want to use that, then go ahead, but an alternative is to have a registry of those classes:

```
const REGISTRY = {} as { [name: string]: { new(): any };

...
class Home { ... }
REGISTRY["Home"] = Home;
```

And then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    arr[i].root = REGISTRY[arr[i].root];
}
```

Another thing is that this approach creates coupling between the data which is returned from the server and the client side.
You always need to make sure that the class names you return in your json have a corresponding implementation on the client side.
If you rename the class in the client side you need to remember to change it on the server as well.
It's better to only return data and then have the client figure out by itself how to act and find the needed classes.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, that make sense